# CakePHP login, password field returns hashed password?

Tags: cakephp, authentication

When I enter username and password on a login form, it doesn't redirect to the `$loginRedirect` path and show the login form again with the password field filled with **the hashed password in the database** for that username!

I use thew `Auth` component and the **sign_me_up** plugin.

This is file `login.ctp`:

```
<?php 
    if($session->check('Message.Auth'))
        $session->flash();
    echo $form->create('User',array('action'=>'/login'));
    echo $form->input('username');
    echo $form->input('password');

    echo $form->end('login');
?>
```

and this is beforeFilter()

```
function beforeFilter(){
    $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'index');            
}
```

The login problem is just for `/` in action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is usually good to empty password field for every failed submission attempt, you can do so by

`echo $form->input('password', array('value' => false));`

I asked a similar question (to my answer) a while back:
[CakePHP: Clearing password field on failed submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318721/cakephp-clearing-password-field-on-failed-submission)